# How to map apache authgroupfile with varnish-cache

Tags: reverse-proxy, varnish, user-roles

## Hi Friends,

Please help, we are trying add user and roles to our legacy application by mapping users in Apache AuthgroupFile with varnish-cache reverse-proxy, any user authenticated through Apache Basic Auth should be able to go through; The user is mapped to the role in the AuthgroupFile and in back-end we check for the group name and assign the role in the application

can we read the AuthgroupFile to a variable and in varnish-cache and check for the REMOTE_USER header?

#AuthgroupFile
admin: foo boo roo
readonly: goo too zoo

#varnish-cache rule

```
if (req.http.REMOTE_USER){
   set req.http.X-AUTH-USER = req.http.REMOTE_USER;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for *authenticated users*, I'd advise you to have a look at [vmod_basicauth](http://git.gnu.org.ua/cgit/vmod-basicauth.git/).

Its a Varnish module that reads an `.htpasswd` file and gives you a *VCL API* to interact with these logins.

Here's how to use this module in VCL:

```
if (!basicauth.match("/var/www/.htpasswd", req.http.Authorization)) {
    return(synth(401, "Restricted"));
}
```

This will match the `Authorization` request header to whatever is allowed in `.htpasswd`.

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Is there a way to check which group the user belongs to, so as we can map the role accordingly

Comment: You can use `std.fileread()` to read the AuthGroupFile. It returns a string. If regex magic allows you to fetch the information you need, it can be done. See https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vmod_std.html#std-fileread for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the support